# Access previous frameset id in other frameset using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, frameset

Can anyone help to solve this issue,

i have few framesets and frames in a single html page like,

```
<frameset id="MainFrame" rows="110,*,0,0" frameborder="0" border="0" onload="FrameonLoad()">    
    <frame id="banner" name="banner" src="banner.shtml" noresize="noresize" scrolling="no" frameborder="0">
      <frameset id="SubFrame" cols="268,*">
        <frame id="tree" name="tree" src="links.htm" noresize="noresize" frameborder="0">           
        <frame id="main" name="main" src="splash.shtml" frameborder="0">                
      </frameset>       
    <frame id="status1" name="status1" src="status.shtml" scrolling="no" frameborder="0">
    <frame id="maps" name="maps" src="globdat.shtml" scrolling="no" frameborder="0">        
</frameset>
```

i need to access frameset with id="MainFrame" being in frame with id="main".

i tried using javascript like,

```
document.getElementById('MainFrame')
```

but no luck.

Any suggestions !

Comment: What do you want to do on accessing the frame?

Comment: on the mainframe i am trying to display a popup window

Answer (score 0):

The `<frame>` tag is not supported in HTML5.
so you have to use `<iframe>` instead.